# most efficient way to remove 100s of dynamic DOM elements

Tags: javascript, dom, memory, automation

I generate 100s of elements in different columns and I need to remove them when they reach certain row count.

I try to do it with the interval, but I wonder if theres more efficient way of doing this:

```
function destroyer() {
    var temp,
    row_count = 20,
    shred = 10;

    shredder = setInterval(function() {
        for(i = 0; i < col_count; i++) {
            elem = eval('col' + i);

            if(elem.childNodes.length > row_count) {
                elem.removeChild(elem.childNodes[row_count]);
            }
        }
    }, shred);
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the eval? Why not just `document.getElementById('col' + i)`?

Comment: In any case, you should do this check when the elements are being created, not at an interval.

Comment: Do you need to remove all raws? You can user elem.innerHTML = '';

Comment: The rows are created top to bottom, and I need to remove every row greater than 20 for each of the columns.

Comment: it has already been said, but you shouldn't use `eval`, it will negatively affect your performance.